# Having trouble getting an answer from a rest service with Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am very new to Spring and I am having trouble getting anything back from a rest service. I would love to get an answer to what I am doing wrong. Thanks in an advance!

This is the rest service from where I am trying to get an answer: 
Here is my code.

```
package testi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import java.util.Arrays;


@SpringBootApplication
public class TestiApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestiApplication.class, args);
}

public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    //Asetettaan otsikkotietueet
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("X-ESA-API-KEY", "ROBOT");

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
    System.out.println("Testing " + entity.getHeaders());

    String answer = restTemplate.postForObject("https://www.veikkaus.fi/api/v1/sport-games/draws?game-names=MULTISCORE", entity, String.class);
    System.out.println(answer);

    //ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://www.veikkaus.fi/api/v1/sport-games/draws?game-names=MULTISCORE", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    //System.out.println(response);

  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the rest service so here it is:
https://github.com/VeikkausOy/sport-games-robot/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Having trouble, as in....? Are you getting an exception? If so, include it in your post.

Comment: What problem are you getting ?

Comment: System.out.println(answer); does not seem to print out anything so I suppose I cant either connect to the rest or it is posting null back?

Sorry for not being very clear. English is not my best language and I am very new to Eclipse and Spring in general.

What I am trying to achieve is to get an json answer.

Comment: where is your service code ?

Comment: I dont have a service code. I think? I could make it after I get the response from the server for I do not know what kind of data it is going to send me back. PS. Thanks for trying to help me out. It must be hard to understand my problem :(

Comment: If it's not printing *anything* then the result is an empty String. Are you sure that the program runs fully?

Comment: When i use Advanced Rest Client to POST to the provided URL and key, i get a 405 Method Not Allowed. If i change the request to a GET, i get a 200 response and what i assume is the data you want.

Comment: Hi, There are no errors showing  in the Problems section of the Eclipse when I am running the program. I am not even certain that my headers and so on are correct, but I suppose since none of you have been saying that they are incorrect they are good.
Doesn't the commented out section of my code where it is using restTemplate.exchange use get? that did not give me any answer back either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API documentation you provided seems to indicate the API you're trying to access uses the GET method. You are making the request with the POST method (`restTemplate.postForObject(...)`).

Try using the GET method via `restTemplate.getForObject(...)`.

In general, when debugging your REST calls, you should also examine the response status code in addition to the response body. In this case this arguably would have yielded the HTTP 405 error indicating what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping me out. So yes I had to use the GET method and I used the restTemplate.exchange there. I also implemented a commandlineRunner which helped. Thanks to everyone!